# setHours to 5pm

Tags: javascript

Ok, this might sound stupid and noob but right now in my js, I have this code:

```
var date = new Date();
    date.setHours(5, 00, 00);
```

which will give me 5:00:00. Is there a way to set it to am/pm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setHours uses 24-hour time. So, 5PM in 24-hour time is 17, i.e.

date.setHours(17,0,0);

From [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setHours.asp).

Comment: @ Michael Todd -- thanks, that did it. I didnt know that setHours uses 24-hour time.

Answer (score 0):

setHours uses a 24-hour time format

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setHours.asp